# I have Ubuntu 14.04. Do I use xscreensaver or gnome screensaver?

Tags: 14.04, screensaver, xscreensaver, gnome-screensaver

I had version 12.04 on another machine. I don't remember the terminal command to get screensavers. I had a simple one called "box fit". Anyone know how I can get the simple screensavers back? I don't even know if it is xscreensaver or gnome-screensaver.

Comment: If a screensaver you want is not installed, look for one in the repositories.

Comment: Where is the repository? Version 14.04 has NO installed screensavers. Thats why I am asking where to find the right ones.

Comment: Well, ...I mean the software center, which gets software from special software repositories.

Comment: gnome-screensaver just provides locking. If you want those flash screensavers, you need to use xscreensaver (the xscreensaver package comes with a lot of screensavers).

Answer (score 2):

The BoxFit screensaver you are after is available as part of the `xscreensaver` package:

[image]

This can simply be installed from the Software Center or by typing the following in a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver
```

More than enough beautiful screensavers there :)

Comment: Excellent :). If my answer has been useful to you consider 'Accepting' it: http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer